# How can I replace words in a string with elements in an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, string, hash

I'm trying to replace words (sequence of characters, more generally) in a string with corresponding values in an array. An example is:

`"The dimension of the square is {{width}} and {{length}}"` with array `[10,20]` should give

`"The dimension of the square is 10 and 20"`

I have tried to use gsub as

```
substituteValues.each do |sub|
    value.gsub(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/, sub)
end
```

But I could not get it to work. I have also thought of using a hash instead of an array as follows:

`{"{{width}}"=>10, "{{height}}"=>20}`. I feel this might work better but again, I'm not sure how to code it (new to ruby). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```rb
h = {"{{width}}"=>10, "{{length}}"=>20}
s = "The dimension of the square is {{width}} and {{length}}"
puts s.gsub(/\{\{(?:width|length)\}\}/, h)
# => The dimension of the square is 10 and 20
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ukFbvr). *Details*:

- `\{\{(?:width|length)\}\}` - a regex that matches

  - `\{\{` - a `{{` substring
  - `(?:width|length)` - a non-capturing group that matches `width` or `length` words
  - `\}\}` - a `}}` substring
- `gsub` replaces all occurrences in the string with
- `h` - used as the second argument, allows replacing the found matches that are equal to hash keys with the corresponding hash values.

You may use a bit simpler hash definition without `{` and `}` and then use a capturing group in the regex to match `length` or `width`. Then you need

```rb
h = {"width"=>10, "length"=>20}
s = "The dimension of the square is {{width}} and {{length}}"
puts s.gsub(/\{\{(width|length)\}\}/) { h[Regexp.last_match[1]] }
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/jYSltr). So, here, `(width|length)` is used instead of `(?:width|length)` and only Group 1 is used as the key in `h[Regexp.last_match[1]]` inside the block.

Comment: More simply `gsub` can take a hash as a second argument structured as a `{match => replacement}` e.g. `s.gsub(/\{\{(?:width|length)\}\}/,h) #=> "The dimension of the square is 10 and 20"`